# If GDAL is compiled against GEOS, is there a way to know on which GEOS version it relies?

Tags: geos

Is there a(n easy) way to know the GEOS version GDAL was compiled with?

I recently faced some strange errors (related to invalid geometries) both in [PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412801/using-st-union-to-aggregate-polygon-parts-resulting-of-st-subdivide-leads-to-a-g) and [rasterio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403523/wrong-features-when-exporting-vectorized-raster-data-to-a-file-using-geopandas-a) and I have the feeling that they may be related through the GEOS version they depend on. Hence this precise question.